# Randomized loading page image in Shiny App

Tags: css, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I have a Shiny app that has several reactive tables that take time to load and have successfully modified the code I found on this website(https://www.listendata.com/2019/07/add-loader-for-shiny-r.html) to have a loading gif display when each tab is selected as the output tables generate (but not when conditional panels are generating).

I would like to randomize the image. I suspect this can be achieved with the shinyJS package but I have very little Java experience and I just can't seem to make sense of it.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)

# User Interface
ui <-
  dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                dashboardHeader(title = "Loading Screen"),
                dashboardSidebar(),
                dashboardBody(
                  
                  # Javasript Code
                  singleton(tags$head(HTML("
<script type='text/javascript'>

/* When recalculating starts, show loading screen */
$(document).on('shiny:recalculating', function(event) {
if(event.target.id === 'plot'){
$('div#divLoading').addClass('show');
}
});

/* When new value or error comes in, hide loading screen */
$(document).on('shiny:value shiny:error', function(event) {
$('div#divLoading').removeClass('show');
});

</script>"))),
                  
                  # CSS Code
                  singleton(tags$head(HTML(paste0("
<style type='text/css'>
#divLoading
{
  display : none;
  }
  #divLoading.show
  {
  display : block;
  position : fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background-image : url('http://northerntechmap.com/assets/img/loading-dog.gif');
  background-size: auto 40%;
  background-repeat : no-repeat;
  background-position : center;
  left : 0;
  bottom : 0;
  right : 0;
  top : 0;
  }
  #loadinggif.show
  {
  left : 50%;
  top : 50%;
  position : absolute;
  z-index : 101;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  margin-left : -16px;
  margin-top : -16px;
  }
  div.content {
  width : 1000px;
  height : 1000px;
  }
  
</style>")))),
                  
                  # HTML Code   
                  
                  box(tags$body(HTML("<div id='divLoading'> </div>")),
                      plotOutput('plot', width = "800px", height = "450px"),
                      actionButton('goPlot', 'Generate Plot', icon("paper-plane"), 
                                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                      width = 12, height = 500)
                  
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$goPlot
    Sys.sleep(3)
    plot(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "randomized" ?

Comment: I want to have 5-10 different GIFS that are randomly used whenever someone runs the program.  Just trying to make it more interesting for the users.